# Passar codigo PHP pro HTML

Tags: php, html

Fiz exatamente o código PHP deste vídeo [clique aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA-IuGdu07U) para fazer com que meu formulário envie os dados para o meu e-mail.

Porém, agora que tenho o código inteiro, não sei como passar o mesmo para o meu html.

Porquê tipo, o exemplo do rapaz ele fez o formulario, ele colocou todo aquele corpo estrutural do HTML, num arquivo PHP.

E o formulario do meu site, tá junto com o site inteiro no arquivo HTML. 
Como eu faria pra fazer funcionar o formulário?

```
<?php
$msg=0;
@$msg= $_REQUEST['msg'];
?>
```

Este código acima, terei que colocar acima do código inicial do html, e se o arquivo for html, não vai funcionar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> etc...
```

E tem um outro arquivo externo php tbm.

Comment: você terá que jogar dentro do arquivo desejado no site e transferir a extensão deste arquivo para .php, mas não terá nenhum problema em fazer isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então Lukas, não é possível incluir um trecho de código PHP em um arquivo HTML, esse mesmo deve ser .php, você deve alterar a extensão do seu arquivo .html para .php e inserir o código.

Você está rodando esse projeto na sua máquina localmente ou está em um servidor online?

Comment: estou usando xampp pra fazer o php, e já está funciando, enviou para o meu e-mail certinho..
então não teria problema eu mudar o arquivo do meu site que é HTML, pra php?

Comment: De forma alguma, só deve atentar para caso tenha criado algum link em outra página dando como referência por exemplo contato.html, nesse link vc vai ter que alterar para contato.php.

Comment: ah sim.. então quando eu for subir o site para o servidor de hospedagem, não tem problema subir o arquivo index, como index.php? 
nao sabia  disso.. sou novato na area, mas, obrigado!